# Pass each row of a dataframe to other dataframes in parallely in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have a usecase iterate over each row from a dataframe and pass it to other dataframe. Below is the code snippet for the same. I would like execute this iterate in parallel. I cannot use rdd.map() as we CANNOT execute Spark drivers code within the Spark workers. Any alternate method to acheive parallelism

```
for row in in0.collect():
 update_config = self.config.update_from_row_map(row, conf_to_column)
 _inputs = inDFs
 results.append(self.__run__(spark, update_config, *_inputs))
```

How can we achieve parallel assigning of rows from in0 to inDFs using spark's parallelism. Is it a good practice to multiprocessing threadpools to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very subjective. Usually you won't use Spark parallelism to perform application functionality. You use it primarily for transformations that take one or more column values and produce one or more transformed values.

That said you can [mis]use it using UDFs, where UDF would take row/columns as input and perform something other than transformation. So something like:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

@F.udf(returnType=IntegerType())
def update_config(**cols):
  row = ','.join(cols)
  # update the config in some DB or whatever...
  return result_of_status_update


in0.alias('in').withColumn('result_of_status_update', update_config('in.*'))
```

Problem is that this would be really slow (compared to a for loop on driver as shown in question), because instead of iterating over a list of rows on driver and processing it, you're adding the overhead of distributing it to worker and then performing the action.

---

Options are:

1. As you mentioned "multiprocessing threadpools" on driver. Problem could be that there are too many rows and driver may not be able to keep it all in memory. I.e. `in0.collect()` causes OOM. Pro, least overhead and would be fast, if row count isn't too big.
2. Delegate the work to workers using UDFs, but do not do all the work inside UDF, instead make UDF async, e.g. using a REST call. Will probably work faster than #1 if you're dealing with really large number of rows. Problem is that it's harder to do error handling and you'll have to make any libraries used in UDF implementation available on workers, e.g. `requests` in this case.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

@F.udf(returnType=IntegerType())
def trigger_config_update_async(**cols):
  import requests
  row = ','.join(cols)
  response = requests.put('http://my-site.com/config', data=row)
  return response.content

in0.alias('in').withColumn('result_of_rest_call', trigger_config_update_async('in.*'))
```

Comment: Thanks for that. On the Option1, i have a control of max rows of 1000 in in0 df. So i dont see any issues with driver OOM. let me know your thoughts

Comment: For a 1000 (or even 5000) rows, IMHO option 1 is the way to go, from performance and ease of implementation point of view. I.e. `collect()` the 1000 rows and then ignore the fact that you're running Spark, just write pure python code that "processes those 1000 rows" without using Spark. E.g. using "multiprocessing threadpools".